# Unresolved androidx classes for writing unit tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, androidx, instrumentation

I am trying to write my first test and I have problem figuring out the right dependencies to get everything to work. Here is my test class

```
class EmployeeDatabaseTest {
    private lateinit var employeeDao: EmployeeDAO

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        EmployeeDatabase.TEST_MODE = true
        employeeDao = EmployeeDatabase.getDatabase(??).employeeDao()
    }

    @Test
    fun should_Insert_Employee_Item() {
        val employee = Employee("xx", "xx", 31, Gender.MALE)
        employee.id = 1
        runBlocking {  employeeDao.addNewEmployee(employee) }
        val employeeTest = runBlocking {  getValue(employeeDao.getEmployeeById(employee.id!!)) }
        Assert.assertEquals(employee.name, employeeTest.name)
    }
}
```

Normally I would obtain context by `InstrumentationRegistry.getContext()...`but `InstrumentationRegistry` can't be resolved. It also can't resolve `getValue(..)` method. I am new to testing but I bet is something with dependencies. Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
   ...
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
}

defaultConfig {
    ...
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Do I miss something I am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In which folder do you have your test files? src/test or src/androidTest?

Comment: @RicardoCosteira I have them in src/test

Comment: @RicardoCosteira And that was the problem. When I moved my tests everything started to work. This is correct solution.

Comment: Thought so :P you're doing instrumentation tests. For instrumentation tests, you need to have your files in the androidTest folder. The test folder is meant for tests that don't require access to the Android framework. The way you import the dependencies also matter, because they affect the different folders. You're importing most of them with `androidTestImplementation`, thus saying you want those dependencies for the androidTest folder. That Junit `testImplementation` you have will only affect the tests inside src/test.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `Context` can be resolved with

```
androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
```

which is part of the core module

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'
```

When you use *Robolectric*, you can also have it as

```
testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'
```

Comment: Thats the whole problem. I have imported before mentioned core package and ApplicationProvider still cannot be resolved.

Comment: Right. AndroidTest and Test have different dependencies. If you use Robolectric, have a look at the answer. If not, you should build your database without context and in memory